# table cells get duplicated when I use EGOTableViewPullRefresh

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm working on a RSS Reader using [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial). All table cells data come from a `NSMutableArray` instance (_allEntries). Then I import 
`EGOTableViewPullRefresh` and add `[self refresh]` in `-(void)reloadTableViewDataSource` (`self.refresh` is a method to populate data of allEntries).
Then pull to refresh works but cells got duplicated every time I refresh. I tried to solve it in two ways.

1. When download data from internet, add `if (![_allEntries containsObject:entry])` before `[_allEntries insertObject:entry atIndex:insertIdx]` but it didn't work, maybe I should use `entry.title` or some other attribute in the object to compare but it's not effective.
2. Like what I did in `-viewDidLoad`, add `self.allEntries = [NSMutableArray array]`, but I don't know where should I put this line.

Is there anyone who can give me a direction?

[EDIT]
There's no too much logic in viewDidLoad, just

```
    self.allEntries = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]; //add download&parse operation to a queue 
    self.feeds = [self getFeeds];  //load feeds from local file
```

And I put [self refresh] in reloadTableViewDataSource, the first time I open my app, there's nothing showed in the tableview. Then I pull to refresh, it works. Then pull to refresh again, it got duplicated.
This is the "refresh" method.

```
    - (void)refresh {
        for (NSString *feed in _feeds) {
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:feed];
            ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
            [request setDelegate:self];
            [_queue addOperation:request];
        }    
    }
```

I want to rebuild the array so I write self.allEntries = [NSMutableArray array] again but it turns out 
**"Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (140)".** 
So as mentioned, I really get confused about where should I put this line.
Thx~~

Answer (score 0):

The logic you have in viewDidLoad that builds your array should be moved to its own method (reloadTableViewData), and then you would just call that method in viewDidLoad.

```
[self reloadTableViewData];
```

You would also call that same method when you do the pull to refresh.

Make sure you are rebuilding that array and not just adding objects to the existing one.